# What datatype to save list in database

Tags: java, mysql

What datatype to use MySQL to save `List` `ArrayList`?
I must write:

```
private List<Exercise> favoriteExerciesList;
```

Comment: @BrettWalker Not quite. Homework questions are OK. Homework dumps are not.

Comment: I dont understand. For example if i want save String i use Varchar. What i must use to save List or ArrayList.

Comment: @davyd I suspect that answer to your question will depend on how you would like to use this list in database. For instance you can simply serialize it in structure like blob, but this will not let you easily search content of that list in DB. So consider adding some informations about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Google for `one-to-map` or `many-to-many` will give u much more idea

Answer (score 0):

The datatype `Exercise` would map to a database table.  Each attribute of `Exercise` would map to a column in the table. So a list of `Exercises` would be multiple row in the exercise table.